# I keep getting Varnish Guru Mediation 503 errors despite setting timeouts

Tags: php, apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, varnish, 503-error

I have the following backend setup:

```
backend seanesopenko {
    .host = "seanesopenko.ca";
    .port = "8080";
    .connect_timeout = 60s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 300s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 60s;

}
```

I still keep getting Guru Mediation 503 errors despite setting the timeouts in the backends.  I think it could be apache2/php errors that are being displayed as Guru Mediation 503 errors by Varnish.  How do I configure varnish/apache to display apache2 errors?

Answer (score 2):

A 503 error from Varnish usually means either:

- You have configured backend health checks and the health check has failed, or
- Varnish is simply unable to contact your backend server (e.g., the connection has taken more than `connect_timeout` seconds, or was refused, etc).

Since (a) doesn't apply to your configuration, I'm guessing (b).  What does the output of `varnishlog` look like?  Have you verified that you can correctly connect to http://seanesopenko.ca:8080/ from your Varnish server?  For example:

```
curl http://seanesopenko.ca:8080/
```

In any case, `varnishlog` should shed some light on the situation.

Comment: Varnishlog is your best friend, if you can watch when the error is happening though varnishlog you'll have a much better idea of what's going wrong.